# Different label types on one axis in chart

Tags: c#, charts

I'm using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` in my app and I want to add different label types on my X axis which is representing a timeline. For example, I want to use `"HH:mm"` format for labels but when it's `00:00` I'd like to show `"dd.MM"` format instead. I tried to add cutom labels but it has no effect at all.

```
var area = new ChartArea();
area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
area.AxisX.Interval = 1 / 24.0;
area.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1.0, DateTimeIntervalType.Days, "dd.MM");
```

Comment: try `area.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1`

Comment: @Mohit Shrivastava it makes labels with 1 day interval but i need them to appear every hour. btw labels with 00:00 don't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `CustomLabels` **will** help; however if you want them to show an individual format you will have to add them individually to **each** `DataPoint`!

Doing so is not quite as simple as one could wish for; there are several overloads but none is really easy to use. The simplest way, imo, is to use one with a `FromPosition` and a `ToPosition`; these should then to be set in a way that they hit right **between** the `DataPoints`; this way they will be centered nicely..

Note that as the X-Values are really `DateTimes`, but as always in a chart, converted to `doubles` we need to convert them back to `DateTime` for correct formatting and also use their values to calculate the middle or rather  half an interval..

Here is an example:

[image]

```
// prepare the test chart..
chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("CA1");
Random R = new Random(123);
chart1.Series.Clear();
CA.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 1;
Series S = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
S.Points.Clear();
S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
S.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "10");
// some random data:
DateTime dt0 = new DateTime(2015, 05, 01);
for (int i = 0; i< 40; i++)
{
    int p = S.Points.AddXY(dt0.AddHours(i), R.Next(100));
}


// each custom label will be placed centered in a range
// so we need an amount of half an interval..
// this assumes equal spacing..
double ih = (S.Points[0].XValue - S.Points[1].XValue) / 2d;

// now we add a custom label to each data point
for (int i = 0; i < S.Points.Count; i++)
{
    DataPoint pt = S.Points[i];
    string s = (DateTime.FromOADate(pt.XValue)).ToString("HH:mm");
    bool midnite = s == "00:00";

    if (midnite) s = DateTime.FromOADate(pt.XValue).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    CustomLabel CL = CA.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(pt.XValue - ih, pt.XValue + ih, s);
    CL.ForeColor = midnite ? Color.Blue : Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much. But what if there is no data points at 00:00? I create ChartArea and Series in different functions and don't know my data points beforehand. So I need my labels to be shown despite incoming data. Is there a way to make this?

Comment: Well, you asked for code that sets a date label at midnight, didn't you? - You can both: modify it for some other or more relaxed condition and also to work right while the data come in. But since I don't see how they come in (added to the points collection? or data-bound? etc..) I can't advide how to do that best..

Comment: Yes, due to my first post I'm marking this as answer anyway.) But in your example you work with existing data points and I wanted to ask can I add my labels when there are no data points. I have a function `public Chart MakeChart(...)` that calls `private ChartArea MakeChartArea(...)` and `private Series MakeSeries(...)`. All data points are counted in `MakeSeries` functions and chart area is prepared in `MakeChartArea` where I'm trying to set my labels and where are no data points. For `MakeSeries` time interval is unknwown value.

Comment: Well you can add them without any DataPoints being there yet, but only if you __know the range__ of `X-Values` they are supposed to label. But if you want or need to you can always __change__ the `FromPosition` and `ToPositions` of each  `AxisX.CustomLabels` element __later__.. - The `CustomLabels` will show as soon as you have added at least one `DataPoint` that fall in the range of one of the Labels